Playwright script works on local but times out randomly on delpoyed image
I have a script which runs perfectly on my laptop but gets timeout on finding an element sometimes on the deployed image on azure.
The script basically loops this on Reddit:

Opens a new chromium browser
Logs in perfectly
Then goes to a post URL
Waits for the add comment  button to be visible: page.wait_for_selector("faceplate-tracker[noun="add_comment_button"] button", timeout=500000)

This is where it randomly times out sometimes, and I can't figure out why.
Here is the full script:
def start():
    global page, browser, playwright
    playwright = sync_playwright().start()
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(os.getcwd() + '\\playwright_data',headless=False)
    page = browser.pages[0]

def login():
    browser.clear_cookies()
    page.goto("https://www.reddit.com/login", timeout=0)
    page.wait_for_load_state()
    page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    

    page.wait_for_selector("input#login-username")
    page.locator("input#login-username").fill(creds)

    page.wait_for_selector("input#login-password")
    page.locator("input#login-password").fill(creds)


    login_button_selector = "button.login:has-text('Log In')"
    page.wait_for_selector(login_button_selector)
    page.click(login_button_selector)
    page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
    
def run():
    start()
    login()
    post_url = # any random reddit post
    try:
        page.goto(post_url)
        page.wait_for_load_state()
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)
Error-> page.wait_for_selector("faceplate-tracker[noun=\"add_comment_button\"] button", timeout=500000)
        page.locator("faceplate-tracker[noun=\"add_comment_button\"] button").click()
     
        page.wait_for_timeout(5000)

        page.wait_for_timeout(3000)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    browser.close()
    playwright.stop()


run()

Here is the docker file:
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10.11

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
        xvfb \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libasound2 \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libnspr4 \
        libgbm1 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libcups2 \
        libxkbcommon0 \
        libatspi2.0-0 \
        libnss3

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && \
    playwright install chromium && \
    playwright install-deps

COPY app.py .
COPY reddit_bot.py .
COPY config.py .
COPY comment.py .
copy posts_replied_to.txt .

EXPOSE 3000
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

ENV DISPLAY=:99

CMD Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16 & python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 

I wanted to run this playwright script on my docker image hosted at azure but it keeps randomly giving timeout 500,000 exceeded: waiting for locator("faceplate-tracker[noun="add_comment_button"] button") to be visible.

Added more details. I can't look at the page, right? It's running on azure

Thanks. Did you try adding a user agent? You can capture the page content and see if there's a block happening there, like a cloudflare notice.

what is a user agent?

See this answer. Also, timeout=0 can hang forever. I'd make that 120_000 or so.
